# javascript time function echoed in php function working?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a php function which when called should spit out a javascript function to show continuously updating time, i.e.- 12:14:51. My php function is getting called and I see the javascript and its related div being sent to the html(developer tool), but the clock is not showing up.
Why?

The code:

```
<?php function add_time() {

        print '<script type="text/javascript">' . 
            'window.onload = function startTime()
                {
                var today=new Date();
                var h=today.getHours();
                var m=today.getMinutes();
                var s=today.getSeconds();
                // add a zero in front of numbers<10
                m=checkTime(m);
                s=checkTime(s);
                document.getElementById(\'txt\').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
                t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
                }

                function checkTime(i)
                {
                if (i<10)
                  {
                  i="0" + i;
                  }
                return i;
                }' .  
        '</script>';



    } // end show content/date
```

Comment: Are you using a framework or CMS? If so, and if the function is being called outside of a template, it could be getting caught by [PHP output buffering](http://us1.php.net/ob_start) you could try adding the line 'while (ob_get_level()) { ob_end_clean(); }' to the end to test this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `startTime()` function somewhere, perhaps on page load.